# How much memory can an iOS app allocate?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm trying to get a feel for the amount of memory an iOS app can reliably allocate to help me drive some design decisions. The app is going to involve real time synchronised processed audio and animation.

Other than writing code that loads up the frameworks I'll need then trying to progressively allocate memory until I get warnings, is there any way to determine this kind of thing?

The simulator doesn't let you select a specific hardware model, so I assume I can't even simulate this stuff.

Comment: You can simulate low memory warnings though, so your app should be able to handle those correctly regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine how much memory an app allocate as far as I know. Always try to keep the lowest memory possible for your app.

The memory allocated to  your app depends on many factors like : number of background process happening, amount of memory available, memory used by other apps, the device you are running etc..

So, its not a good practice to keep a maximum line for memory consumed by your app and design accordingly. 
Also try to hold only the necessary memory you need and handle memory issue in the memory callback methods like 'didreceivememorywarning'. Always consider that you have the least amount of memory allocated by the OS.